# fluentui/react change the height of the panel

Tags: reactjs, fluentui-react

Is there a way to make the fluent ui panel smaller in height? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/panel

My page has two divs. One header div and one content div. I would like the panel to occupy/open only the same height as the content div. Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLmsV.png)

I couldn't find any examples

Comment: You can achieve that trough `styles={{ root: { height: 200 } }}` for example. But from my perspective that's gonna "destroy" idea of Panel Component. It looks much better with 100% height... https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/dyKqzag?editors=0010

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I know but that's the requirement. How can I set the height to auto, so if fits in the window between the header div and the end of the screen?
using px and a fixed height is not ideal.

Comment: Can you share your code?  I tried this in codepen using position:absolute and it worked but this might not be the best approach for what you are doing

Comment: @DonaldKoscheka I will try to create it in the codepen and I will share it with you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Panel is the right component to be used in that case. If you want a non-full height panel, it could be a [Callout](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/callout)
or a [Modal](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/modal).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).